# Javascript extract value from string

Tags: javascript, string

I am using jQuery jTable plugin to display a session variable data stored in my mysql db which will be in the format:

```
gateway|i:1;FirstName|s:7:"Shelley";LastName|s:2:"VS";Status|s:7:"Enabled";UID|s:10:"b81ef6a12a";AdminGroup|s:8:"Sysadmin";
```

I am displaying all the session data in a jtable column which is not required. I need to extract only the `FirstName` portion from the string using JavaScript. I am a javascript newbie. I did the following:

```
name: {
    title: 'Admin Name',
    display: function (data) {
        var x = data.record.data;
        if(x.match("FirstName")) {
            return "yes";
        }
    },
},
```

Which displays "yes" in my new `jtable` column as `FirstName` data is found in string using x.match. How can I **extract only the first name portion** from the above text using javascript. I will have multiple records in the same format.

Thanks in advance.

**Added to my original post**

@cytofu Excellent answer to a newbie..I changed the code to suit my jTable (without an additional function) as follows and it is running fine: Thank you.

```
firstname: {
title: 'First Name',                    
display: function (data) {
var str = data.record.data;
var startOfSection = str.indexOf('FirstName');
var startOfValue = str.indexOf('"',startOfSection)+1;
var endOffValue  = str.indexOf('"',startOfValue); //one char longer, as needed for   substring
var value = str.substring(startOfValue,endOffValue);
return value;
},
},

//last name

lastname: {
title: 'Last Name',                    
display: function (data) {
var str = data.record.data;
var startOfSection = str.indexOf('LastName');
var startOfValue = str.indexOf('"',startOfSection)+1;
var endOffValue  = str.indexOf('"',startOfValue); //one char longer, as needed for substring
var value = str.substring(startOfValue,endOffValue);
return value;
},
},
```

Comment: I don't recognise the format, what is it? Is there any particular reason not to use XML or JSON?

Comment: Rather then writing a custom parser, let's consider the source, that is if it is accessible. You wouldn't by chance be using [PHP's serialize function](http://php.net/serialize), would you (it looks like you just swapped out the {} with |)? If this is the case, rather than serializing, consider [encoding as JSON with json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) since it can be easily decoded (parsed) in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this function to the script:

```
function extractValue(str,searchStr){

    var startOfSection = str.indexOf(searchStr);
    var startOfValue = str.indexOf('"',startOfSection)+1;
    var endOffValue  = str.indexOf('"',startOfValue); //Position of first char AFTER the value, as needed for substring

    var value = str.substring(startOfValue,endOffValue);

    return value;
}
```

you can test it with:

```
var str = 'gateway|i:1;FirstName|s:7:"Shelley";LastName|s:2:"VS";Status|s:7:"Enabled";UID|s:10:"b81ef6a12a";AdminGroup|s:8:"Sysadmin";';
var searchStr = 'FirstName|';

alert (extractValue(str,searchStr));
```

change your jTable function fragment as follows:

```
name: {
    title: 'Admin Name',
    display: function (data) {
        var x = data.record.data;
        if(x.match("FirstName")) {
            return extractValue(x,"FirstName");
        }
    },
},
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nBG89/7/

Comment: Running it in fiddle produces no result ??

Comment: alert returns the result..But return ( firstName ); produces no output ??

Comment: it was logging the output to console, I changed it to alert the result instead. Also I removed the ; from the beginning of the searchstring, so that it can also be found if it is the first entry.

Comment: I would advise that you go trough some basic JS tutorials or get a text book! return is not a function, it is used in functions to return values.

Comment: I need to display the result and hence a return value is expected. Does not require an alert ?? The answer provided by user Tommi above is perfect. changed alert to return and i was able to produce the result..I am a javascript newbie as referred to in my earlier post...sorry for the silly questions.

Comment: And I am using the code inside a jTable function as follows:                name: {
                        title: 'Admin Name',                    
                         display: function (data) {
                          var x = data.record.data;
                          var patient = 'gateway|i:1;FirstName|s:7:"Shelley";LastName|s:2:"VS";Status|s:7:"Enabled";UID|s:10:"b81ef6a12a";AdminGroup|s:8:"Sysadmin";';
                                                return(patient.match(/FirstName\|\w\:\d+\:\"(\w+)\"/)[1]);
},
},

Comment: in case its somehow not obvious: you can get the value of any other section, by replacing "FirstName" with the SectionName (e.g. LastName or UID or.....)

Comment: +1Great answer..Changed a bit to suit jTable  without an additional function . Added to my original post

Comment: it would be smarter to keep it in a seperate funktion, 1st its easier to read, second its easier to make changes. Lets say the format changes one day, or you find a better solution. With a seperate function you change one place: the function. 
When you add it like you did you have to do the changes everywhere..

Comment: yes i do agree but did it due to difficulty in adding new functions to jtable. Documentation for jtable is poor with no advanced examples.

Comment: one more Note: this solution will fail if the value contains escaped " ( \" ) since it will regard those as the end. --> Therefore it would def. be better to switch the format to json or xml, as suggested in the comments.
But for the sections you have its unlikely to have a problem.. unless you have William "The Fridge" Perry in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You have three common ways:

- parse whole string to object. `.split()` is your best friend in this case;
- change incoming format to JSON;
- get your data with regex:

  `var patient = 'gateway|i:1;FirstName|s:7:"Shelley";LastName|s:2:"VS";Status|s:7:"Enabled";UID|s:10:"b81ef6a12a";AdminGroup|s:8:"Sysadmin";';`

  `alert(patient.match(/FirstName\|\w\:\d+\:\"(\w+)\"/)[1]);`

Comment: You can add another regex with `LastName` in it, **but** in case you need more then two items from string, it's better to parse whole string and it's fields.